# using particular webfont to a html emailing and newsletter

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm really new here, but I been reading a lot of information and help from this community you are really awesome! at this time I need little help with html and css.

I do have an client who need a particular font for the newsletters and email html arts, I been trying many options from here and other resources, but the font still not show on the html arts.

we upload the font to some server to use but nothing, and this font are not in googlefont or any other cdn services.

Can anyone give me a little help?

here is my code

````
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
      <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <!--<title>¡Feliz Aniversario!</title>-->
    <style>
    @import url("http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfonts/stylesheet.css");
</style>
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: "DeliveryRegular";
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: local("Delivery Regular"), local("DeliveryRegular");
            src: url("http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF/Delivery_W_Rg.woff") format("woff");
            src: url("http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF2/Delivery_W_Rg.woff2") format("woff2");
            src: url("http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/TTF/Delivery_Rg.ttf") format("ttf");
            src: url("http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/EOT/Delivery_W_Rg.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'DeliveryBold';
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: local('Delivery Bold'), local('DeliveryBold'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF/Delivery_W_Bd.woff') format('woff'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF2/Delivery_W_Bd.woff2') format('woff2'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/TTF/Delivery_Bd.ttf') format('ttf'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/EOT/Delivery_W_Bd.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
        }
        @font-face {font-family: 'DeliveryCondensedBlack';
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: local('Delivery Condensed Black'), local('DeliveryCondensedBlack'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF/Delivery_W_CdBlk.woff') format('woff'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/WOFF2/Delivery_W_CdBlk.woff2') format('woff2'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/TTF/Delivery_CdBlk.ttf') format('ttf'),url('http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/webfont/EOT/Delivery_W_CdBlk.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        body,table,thead,tbody,tr,td,img {padding: 0;margin: 0;border: none;border-spacing: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;vertical-align: top;}
        /* Add some padding for small screens */
        .encabezadoUno,.encabezadoDos{color: #D40511;}
        p{color:#333333;}
        .wrapper {padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;}
        /*h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {margin: 0;padding: 0;padding-bottom: 20px;line-height: 1.6;font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;}*/
        .bloqueEncabezado{text-align:center;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;}
        .encabezadoUno{font-family: 'DeliveryBold';font-size:1.45em;margin-top:15%;}
        .encabezadoDos{font-family: 'DeliveryRegular';font-size:1.4em;}
        p{font-family: 'DeliveryRegular';font-size:1.2em;text-align:center;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;}
        .nombre{font-family: 'DeliveryCondensedBlack';font-size:2.6em;color:#D40511;text-align:center;padding-bottom:5%;text-transform: uppercase;}
        img {width: 100%;display: block;}
        .bg_yellow,.wrapper .section{background:#FFCC00;}
        .txt_dark{background:#333333;}
        .txt_red{color:#D40511;}
        .headImage{padding-bottom:5%;}
        .footerImage{padding-bottom:5%;}
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .wrapper .section {width: 100%;}
            .wrapper .column {width: 100%;display: block;}
            .encabezadoUno{font-size:1.19em;}
            .encabezadoDos{font-size:1.18em;}
            p{font-size:1em;}
            .nombre{font-size:1.8em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wrapper" width="800" align="center">
                    <!-- Header image -->
                    <table class="section header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td >
                                                <img class="headImage" src="http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/images/head-acb-tarjeta-aniversario.jpg" alt="abc" width="800" />
                                                <div class="bloqueEncabezado">
                                                    <span class="encabezadoUno">¡txt</span><br/>
                                                    <span class="encabezadoDos">txt!</span><br/><br/>
                                                </div>
                                                <p>txt:</p>
                                                <div class="nombre">
                                                @@nombre@@
                                                </div>    
                                                <p> txt.<br/><br/>
                                                txt<br/><br/>
                                                txt<br/></p>
                                            </td>  
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td >
                                                <img class="footerImage" src="http://www.mywebsite/clients/abc/images/footer-abc-tarjeta-aniversario.jpg" alt="abc" width="800" />
                                            </td>  
                                        </tr>    
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an HTML formatted email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372719/how-do-i-create-an-html-formatted-email)

Comment: It won't work on almost every email client. You can read [article](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts/) about it at Litmus.com.

Comment: Hi Guys!
Sorry, I'm trying with the info of mohammedkhan, still not working, I'll read all the article again. i'll let you know ASAP.

Comment: Hi Guys!
Nop, did't work, I don't get it  :(